# Need help sending user input to another method

Tags: java, mysql, crud

Let me give a quick explanation. I took a 5 week course through a company on Java in July. They covered basic stuff, like console app, crud operations, mysql, and n-tier architecture. Since the course ended I didn't use it much because I went back to work, and other medical reasons surfaced....blah blah.

I was told by the company to make a simple program to reflect what I learned. Turns out I retained very little.

I decided to make a video game starage program. It would be used to stare your video games so you wouldn't have to search your bookcase(or how ever you store your games.)

To cut to the chase I can't seem to get user input from one clas to another. My method AddGame In my presentation layer is supposed to send the user input to the NewGame method in my logic layer. the error i keep getting is that column 'title' cannot be null.

Here is my AddGame method

```
    public static Games AddGame() {
    Games g = new Games();
    Logic aref = new Logic();
    Scanner scanline = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the title of your game:");
    scanline.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the rating of your game:");
    scanline.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the platform for your game:");
    scanline.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please thenter the developer of your game:");
    scanline.nextLine();
    aref.NewGame(g);
    return g;

}
```

here is my NewGame Method

```
    public static void NewGame(Games g)
{
    try {
         Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
         PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO games(Title,Rating,Platform,Developer) " +
                "VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
         ps.setString(1, g.getTitle());
         ps.setString(2, g.getRating());
         ps.setString(3, g.getPlatform());
         ps.setString(4, g.getDeveloper());
         ps.executeUpdate();
         conn.close();

         } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

I have not learned how to use hibernate and only know how to make a console app. Everything I have looked up has either been hibernate or web app. (sorry if code seems sloppy or crappy)
Please any advice would be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you to use some hibernate tutorial with mysql, good options are mykong tutorials http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/hibernate-tutorials/

Comment: Don't forget to accept one of the answers if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your game class has setters for the instance variables,

use this

```
System.out.println("Please enter the title of your game:");
g.setTitle(scanner.nextLine());

System.out.println("Please enter the rating of your game:");
g.setRating(scanner.nextLine());

System.out.println("Please enter the platform for your game:");
g.setPlatform(scanner.nextLine());

System.out.println("Please thenter the developer of your game:");
g.setDeveloper(scanner.nextLine());
```

nextLine method returns the line of text entered by the user, that data is getting stored in the Games' object's instance variable using setters.

Comment: PRAYERS ANSWERED! Thank you.

Comment: @user2910146 Since you have access to all the data you need to construct your `Games` object, use a [constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19535315/474189) to populate your object rather than multiple calls to `setXXX`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `AddGame` method, you do not populate your `Games` object with any data. You read the data from the user, but just throw it away.

I suggest you add a constructor to your `Games` object that accepts all the necessary parameters, e.g.:

```
public static Games addGame() {

    Scanner scanline = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the title of your game:");
    String title = scanline.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the rating of your game:");
    String rating = scanline.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the platform for your game:");
    String platform = scanline.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please thenter the developer of your game:");
    String developer = scanline.nextLine();

    Games g = new Games(title, rating, platform, developer);
    aref.NewGame(g);
    return g;
}
```

*Side note: Java methods should be `camelCase`, e.g. `addGame` and `newGame`.*

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious problem I am seeing is here:

```
Games g = new Games();
Scanner scanline = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the title of your game:");
scanline.nextLine();
System.out.println("Please enter the rating of your game:");
scanline.nextLine();
System.out.println("Please enter the platform for your game:");
scanline.nextLine();
System.out.println("Please thenter the developer of your game:");
scanline.nextLine();
```

You are essentially ignoring whatever is the user passing. I am assuming that you want to do something like so:

```
Scanner scanline = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the title of your game:");
g.setTitle(scanline.nextLine());
...
```

This will essentially populate your `Games` object. The issue you are having is that the `Games` object is initialized but never really populated with anything, which causes the program complain about `null` values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code as below

You need to pass the values from  `scanline.nextLine();` to your `g.setTitle(),`  `g.setRating()`,`g.setPlatform()`and `g.setDeveloper().`

```
System.out.println("Please enter the title of your game:");
g.setTitle(scanline.nextLine());
System.out.println("Please enter the rating of your game:");
g.setRating(scanline.nextLine());
System.out.println("Please enter the platform for your game:");
g.setPlatform(scanline.nextLine());
System.out.println("Please thenter the developer of your game:");
g.setDeveloper(scanline.nextLine());
aref.NewGame(g);
```